# Error:(17, 34) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]

Tags: java

I just started learning this and can not figure out why a have this problem:

> "Error:(17, 34) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to `int[]`" Help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Vvedite razmer massiva (2 chisla");
        int size1 = sc.nextInt();
        int size2 = sc.nextInt();
        int [] [] array = new int  [size1] [size2];
        System.out.println("Vvedite chisla massiva");
        for (int i=0; i< size1*size2; i++) {
            array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Vash massiv:");

        for (int i=0; i< size1*size2; i++){
            System.out.print (array [i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();


        }
    }
```

Comment: `array` is 2D array, and thus `array[i]` is a 1D array.

Comment: You can also read this: [trying to fill a 2D array by user-input how to do it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27654491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a 2D array , but you are trying to fill it by using only one dimension

```
for (int i=0; i< size1; i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<size2;j++)
        array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

you do the same for displaying the array

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you, if my answer helped you, you can accept it , or put +1

Answer (score 0):

Think of `array[][]` as of **array of arrays**. So, at `array[i]` there is an **array of ints**, not **int** (int is at `array[i][j]`, for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's clear for me now :)

Comment: @ІринаЧистякова Glad that I could help you :-)